# Javascripts not initiating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

A wordpress site that I've been working seems to have something weird about the initiation of some of its scripts. The one that I am currently most concerned with is the drop-down header. It is obviously un-styled as I am just experimenting, but, if you look, it shouldn't be dropping down until a certain length down the page, and while it does that, on page load, it shows itself unti user interaction. Does anyone know what this might be happening? Any help would be much appreciated.

The site link it [nextworld.kbddev.com](http://nextworld.kbddev.com)

Here is my code for the bar:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 542){
          $("#follownav").slideDown("fast");
          $('#follownav').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

      }
    });
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(window).scrollTop() < 542){
          $("#follownav").slideUp("fast");
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The scroll event fires whenever you scroll, making your function fire again and again when the page is scrolled, and whenever the scrollTop is above or below that number, the sliding and changing of classes happens thousands of times. You should limit it somehow, by checking if it's visible or some other way of knowing that you already did the sliding, to avoid it from firing the function over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it your not checking on page load.

A simple fix would be:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll();
});
```

Comment: not true... window exists before code is run. You can bind events to `window` or `document` outside of `document.ready`

Comment: any time you use `$` jQuery has to be loaded before it. Your code will fail if it isn't also

Comment: Okay, give me a second, I'll edit my answer as i better understand the problem

Comment: So, I should just enclose the entire thing in a $(function() {}); ? I tried that and it is still doing the same thing...  Refer to the edit above.  Thanks a lot for the help, by the way.

Comment: @HunterRose i edited my answer, charliefl correctly pointed out i was on the wrong track. Have a look at the new answer, keep your old code the way it was and add this.